# Swipe up and down like control center in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture, ios-animations

I want to swipe up and down main view of `UIViewController` like **control center in iOS**.

I've view of VC2 that is visible half on VC1. Now when user swipe VC2's view using fingers it will swipe up and down like control center.

I did swipe up and down using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but its not animated like **control center in iOS**

**Edit:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDownHandler:)];
      [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
      [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

      UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpHandler:)];
      [gestureRecognizer1 setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
      [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer1];
}

-(void)swipeUpHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,25, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];
}

-(void)swipeDownHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];

}
```

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: How do you expect to get help without any code?

Comment: @Desdenova Please check my edited question.

Comment: You are animating the view for 0.3 seconds. Obviously it's not the desired effect. Check `UIResponder`'s touch events and move the view in `touchesMoved:withEvent:`.